# How to fix "failed to register 'filter errorpagefilterregistration' on the servlet context. possibly already registered?"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, filter, spring-security

I run my app on tomcat 10.1.12 by war file and get

[error message from log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7C80.png)

but if I run on Eclipse (Spring boot 3.1.2), it does not have problem.

Help me please! I try in every way that I can find.

dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import backend.service.UsersService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UsersService usersService;
    private final JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(UsersService usersService, JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter) {
        this.usersService = usersService;
        this.jwtAuthorizationFilter = jwtAuthorizationFilter;

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder)
            throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http
                .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(usersService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/api/authtoken/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

JwtAuthorizationFilter.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JwtAuthorizationFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil, ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        Map<String, Object> errorDetails = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            String accessToken = jwtUtil.resolveToken(request);
            if (accessToken == null ) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request);

            if(claims != null & jwtUtil.validateClaims(claims)){
                String email = claims.getSubject();
                Authentication authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email,"",new ArrayList<>());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            errorDetails.put("message", "Authentication Error");
            errorDetails.put("details",e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

            mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), errorDetails);

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

JwtUtil.java:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import backend.model.Users;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    private final String secret_key = "testSecretKeyForAPIProjectNumber1AndTestSecretKeyForTestProjectNumber1";
    private long accessTokenValidity = 10;

    private final JwtParser jwtParser;

    private final String TOKEN_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public JwtUtil(){
        this.jwtParser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret_key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String createToken(Users user) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(user.getUsername());
        claims.put("firstName",user.getFirstName());
        claims.put("lastName",user.getLastName());
        Date tokenCreateTime = new Date();
        Date tokenValidity = new Date(tokenCreateTime.getTime() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(accessTokenValidity));
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setExpiration(tokenValidity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret_key)
                .compact();
    }

    private Claims parseJwtClaims(String token) {
        return jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public Claims resolveClaims(HttpServletRequest req) {
        try {
            String token = resolveToken(req);
            if (token != null) {
                return parseJwtClaims(token);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            req.setAttribute("expired", ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            req.setAttribute("invalid", ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER);
        
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            return bearerToken.substring(TOKEN_PREFIX.length());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateClaims(Claims claims) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            return claims.getExpiration().after(new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public String getEmail(Claims claims) {
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

}
```

UsersService:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import backend.model.Users;
import backend.repository.UsersRepository;

@Service
public class UsersService implements UserDetailsService {
    
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    public UsersService(UsersRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    
    public Users getByUsername (String username) {
        return userRepository.getByUsername(username);
    }
    
    public Users getByEmail (String email) {
        return userRepository.getByEmail(email);
    }
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userRepository.getByUsername(username);
        UserDetails userDetails =
                org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                        .username(user.getUsername())
                        .password(user.getPassword())
                        .build();
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs

springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-custom.html

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testProjectDB;encrypt=false
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.mapping-resources=Users.hbm.xml,MeterProfileDetail.hbm.xml,TblMeter.hbm.xml,TblEnergy.hbm.xml,TblElectrical.hbm.xml
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.resources.static-locations classpath:/resources/

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same problem as you today and played around a lot, but unfortunately could not find the cause of the problem.
What I did find, however, is that the error does not occur when using a Spring boot version <=3.0.11 (i.e. any version >= 3.1.0 failed), at least in my case.

So if downgrading is a possible workaround for you, just add `<version>3.0.11</version>` to `pom.xml` under `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>`, `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>` and `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>`.